# For loop problems in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a 365x1 vector called dv (day value). I am applying a function to generate some hourly values, hv. My codes are as follows:

```
sigma<-0.246*dv
stime<-function(x,y,z){(exp(-(x-12)^2/(2*y^2))+cos(pi*(x-12)/(z-1)))/(2*y*sqrt(2*pi))}
t<-1:24
hv<-NULL
for (i in seq(along=t)){hv<-c(hv,mapply(stime,t[i],sigma,dv))}
```

I want to the first 24 values using `t[1],t[2],...t[24]` with `z=dv[1]` and the next 24 values to  use `z=dv[2]` etc. But what this code does is to have first 365 values `dv[1],dv[2]...dv[365]` to take `t[1]` then the next 365 values to take `t[2]`...I am not sure if I explain this clearly. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R is vectorised for `exp`, `cos`, `sqrt` and all arithmetic operators so all you really need to do is loop along your `dv` values.

Here is an example using your function with `sapply`, and only the first 3 `t` values for brevity...

```
dv <- 1:5
sapply( dv , function(i) stime( x = t[1:3] , y = 0.246*i , z = i ) )

     [,1]       [,2]          [,3]       [,4]          [,5]
[1,]  NaN -0.4054291 -6.621773e-16  0.1013573 -1.146727e-01
[2,]  NaN  0.4054291 -2.702861e-01 -0.1013573  7.689812e-16
[3,]  NaN -0.4054291  1.489523e-16 -0.2027146  1.146727e-01
```

So there is one value for `z` (which is the current `dv` value), one value for `y` which is 0.246 * current `dv` value, and the 3 values of `t` for `x`. Output is 3 values, one for each `t`, the sigma and `dv` values are recycled and reused each time.

The `NaN`s in the first column are caused by the fact that in this example the first value of `t` and also `dv` are 1, which leads to

```
cos(pi * (1 - 12)/(1 - 1))
```

Which simplifies to;

```
cos(-Inf)
NaN
```

So the result must be `NaN` in this example (hopefully this is not the case in your real data).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
hv <- stime( x =rep(dv, each= 24), y=rep(1:24, each=365), z=x)
```